# Server.MapPath Could not find a part of the path in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the slide show that get the images in my local folder to display in my Site.Master page.

So I used :

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~" + "/path/blahblah/")).GetFiles();
```

It works fine for me when I run the project in the local, but now I changed my project throw the port `http://195.155.10.521:8081`, then it had one error `Could not find a part of the path 'D:\path\blahblah\'`.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me!

Comment: First, I would not have three logical steps jammed into one line of code.  It's just begging for trouble.  1)  Use MapPath to return a string.  2)  Use the string to create a Directory object.  3) Call GetFiles on the object.  At least then you'll know what step is having a problem.

Comment: What version of mvc are you using?

Comment: @SteveWellens The approach you are saying is good at the time of debugging but in that way you endup creating more temporary variables and they makes code mess (I felt sometimes).

Comment: @Mark You are incorrect.  It is easier to read and easier to debug.  The cost of a few temporary variables is nothing compared to the immense benefits of more understandable code.

Answer (score 0):

The port number on which the site is hosted doesn't really matter for the `Server.MapPath` method. So try splitting the method calls in order to more easily identify the problem:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/path/blahblah/");
var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var files = di.GetFiles();
```

If the error message you are getting is `Could not find a part of the path 'D:\path\blahblah\'` then this probably means that the `D:\path\blahblah\` folder doesn't exist on your server.

Comment: Why do you think they are unnecessary? For me the `var` keyword is one of the greatest things of C#, especially in code examples like this where it is obvious what the types are.

Comment: The are unnecessary because you don't need them.  I blogged about it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/11/19/can-the-c-var-keyword-be-misused.aspx  The vast majority of the comments agree with the opinion.  And, from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx  "However, the use of var does have at least the potential to make your code more difficult to understand for other developers. For that reason, the C# documentation generally uses var only when it is required."

Comment: @SteveWellens, I am afraid that our opinions diverge in this case. I respect yours though.

Comment: -Darin, As I pointed out, it's not just my opinion, it seems to be the majority's opinion and Microsoft's opinion.  However, as long as I and anyone on my team don't have to maintain your code, we are fine!

Comment: @SteveWellens, there are cases where the var keyword is very handy and should be used. Eric Lippert summarizes them in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx). I just cannot agree with you that you should never use them except when it is required (anonymous types) and one of the designers of the C# language also seems to support their usage when appropriate. This doesn't mean that they should be used all the time. I didn't say that. I just said that the var keyword has its usage.

Comment: But I would suggest you for us to stop this discussion here because neither of us will convince the other. You can continue to write code like this `Dictionary<string, List<decimal>> prices = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();` while I would write it like this `var prices = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();`. I am also glad that I am not part of your team having to maintain code written by it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var path = Server.MapPath("~/Reproting/Cashstatement.pdf");
 byte[] FileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
 return File(FileBytes, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.